# Unity, Google Play Console and OpenGLES versions

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, google-play-console

I have a very simple question. I am now uploading an app to Google Play for the first time. The app was made in Unity and it allows OpenGLES 2 and OpenGLES 3 however it runs much better with the latter. In my APK info that I can access via Google Play Console, it says:

OpenGL ES versions: 2.0+

I just wanted to make sure that 2.0+ means all OpenGLES versions including and greater than 2.0. That means 3.0, 3.1, 3.2 etc as well.  Is that correct? I really wouldn't want to release the app without OpenGLES 3 by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

According to [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#compatibility):

> The OpenGL ES 3.0 API provides additional features and better performance than the 2.0 API and is also **backward compatible**.

I. e. OpenGL ES 3 is a superset of OpenGL ES 2.

So you can set the requirement as OpenGL ES 2.0+ without a doubt.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I read that too but I was doubtful because if Open GL ES 3 is the superset, which would make OpenGL ES 2 a subset, then shouldn't the info say "Open GL ES 3.0+" instead? That would include both version for sure.

Comment: @YigitBireroglu Nope. ES3 has all the functions of ES2 plus some others. If you set it to ES 3.0+ then it will only allow 3.0, 3.1, 3.2.